# The cofinality of $(\mathbb{N}^\kappa,\le)$ for uncountable $\kappa$?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups, foundations

For a partially ordered set $P$, a set $A\subseteq P$ is *cofinal* if for each element of $P$ there is a larger element in $A$. The *cofinality* of $P$, ${\rm cof}(P)$, is the minimal cardinality of a cofinal family in $P$.

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal number.
Consider the set $\mathbb{N}^\kappa$ of all functions from $\kappa$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (equivalently, $\kappa$-sequences of natural numbers), with the pointwise partial order: $f\le g$ if $f(\alpha)\le g(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$.

Let 
$$f(\kappa):={\rm cof}(\mathbb{N}^\kappa,\le).$$
The cardinal $f(\aleph_0)$ is the well-understood dominating number $\mathfrak{d}$, which is consistently any cardinal of uncountable cofinality that is not larger than the continuum (see [Blass](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/hbk.pdf)).

Basic facts include:

1. For cardinal numbers $\kappa\le\mu$, we have that $f(\kappa)\le f(\mu)$:
   A projection of a cofinal family in $\mathbb{N}^\mu$ on the first $\kappa$ corrdinates is cofinal in $\mathbb{N}^\kappa$.
2. $\kappa<f(\kappa)$: Given $\{h_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}\subseteq\mathbb{N}^\kappa$, define $h(\alpha):=h_\alpha(\alpha)+1$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$.
3. The value of $f(\kappa)$ with "$\le$" replaced by eventual dominance remains the same (see [Comfort](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/106682/CommentatMathUnivCarol_029-1988-4_5.pdf)).

Some deeper results:

1. [Jech-Prikry](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2F4622_1176E3359F6DC1B50E531EBE349A0A5F_journals__PSP_PSP95_01_S0305004100061272a.pdf&cover=Y&code=f33a33db8489693def0a6e06d5ccf9fa): Assume that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is regular and smaller than $2^{\aleph_1}$. If $f(\aleph_1)=2^{\aleph_0}$, then
   there is an inner model with a measurable cardinal.
2. If $\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$, then $f(\kappa)=2^\kappa$ (see [Hathaway](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7948)).

I did not conduct an extensive literature search. I would appreciate your pointing out relevant results that are not mentioned here.

**Question:** 
Are there additional cardinals $\kappa$ for which $f(\kappa)$ can be evaluated in ZFC?

(The question also applies to large cadrinals. I do not request that the cardinals provably exist.)

**Update.** Intially, I also asked whether
$\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$ could be weakened to 
${\rm cof}([\kappa]^{\aleph_0},\subseteq)=\kappa$.
Todd Eisworth reminds in the comments below that the latter hypothesis is true in ZFC for $\aleph_1$.

Strangely, I couldn't find an explicit reference for the following.

**Question.** Is it consistent (modulo suitable large cardinals) that $f(\aleph_1)<2^{\aleph_1}$? Assuming that (See Assaf Rinot's comment below), is there an explicit reference for that?

**Motivation:** The values $f(\kappa)$ pop up whenever I study (usually, jointly with colleagues) the character and other cardinal invariants of topological groups. They are unavoidable.

(Comment: By no means do I mean that the symbol $f(\kappa)$ should be reserved for the function thus defined. This is just a short, temporary name for brevity.)

Comment: If the weakened implication in (2) holds then we would have $f(\aleph_1)=2^{\aleph_1}$ in ZFC.

Comment: @ToddEisworth could you provide some details, or a reference?

Comment: A wild guess concerning the consistency of $f(\aleph_1)<2^{\aleph_1}$: have a careful look at Komjath-Shelah model of [F1445].

Comment: In the particular case where $\kappa=\aleph_1$, one may show that not only CH, but also $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$, is enough to imply that $f(\aleph_1)=2^{\aleph_1}$. See Jech's book for a reference (Chapter 29).

Comment: Just observe that the cofinality of $([\aleph_1]^{\aleph_0},\subseteq)$ is $\aleph_1$, as witnessed by initial segments.  Same holds for all the $\aleph_n$ by induction.

Comment: Should have said "stronger implication" as the assumption is weaker...

Comment: @Todd: Oops. I should have considered these immediate cases. Thanks for pointing this out. Will update the question accordingly.

Comment: @BoazTsaban:  Jech's Chapter 29 mentions that the question of whether $f(\aleph_1)<2^{\aleph_1}$ is consistent is open, and I seem to recall that the question was also mentioned in the original "green version" of his book from 1978.

Comment: @ToddEisworth I had such a feeling from what I did see in the literature. This is absurd that such a "simple" question is still open. I wonder if Shelah knows about it (probably not, for otherwise it should have been solved :) ). I'll have a chance to mention/remind/motivate it to him and others next week, in my lecture at the YST. Would appreciate any futher info about this problem that I can mention then.

Comment: The Komjath-Shelah model does not involve large cardinals. Just force to add $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ many Cohen reals over a model of $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1, 2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2, 2^{\aleph_2}=\aleph_{\omega_1+1}$ and $(\aleph_{\omega_1})^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega_1}$. E.g., force with $Add(\aleph_2,\aleph_{\omega_1+1})*Add(\omega,\aleph_{\omega_1})$ over a model of GCH.